# Can the topological assumption in Debreu's representation theorem of cardinal utility be altered from "connected separable" to "second countable"?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, decision-theory, theory

> Theorem ([Debreu 1959](https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/d00/d0076.pdf) page 9, 10) Let $X$ be connected separable topological space endowed with product topology. *If $\succsim$ is independent and at least three factors are essential, then there exist functions $u_i:X_i\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that*
> $$
> x\succsim y\iff \sum_{i=1}^n u_i (x_i) \geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n u_i (y_i).
> $$

**Question**: can the assumption of **"connected separable**" be changed to "**second countable**"?

I think the primary reason of using "connected separable" is for solvability and cardinality restriction, and second countability is usually stronger than topological separability.

**Motivation:** Debreu' representation theorem of *ordinal* utility uses either "connected separable" or "second countable". Many follow-up of Debreu's work in ordinal utility uses the assumption of "second countable", not "connected separable". This leads to a diverge of assumptions in two strands of literature.

Comment: Debreu's theorem is stronger; the additive representation is unique up to a positive linear representation. This uniqueness will certainly fail without connectedness; you can construct counterexamples with $X$ finite.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Good point!

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker If I am only interested in the existence of utility function (not cardinal uniqueness), can the assumption of connected separable be relaxed to second countable?

Comment: I don't know the answer.